# Joining three columns from three tables and then grouping the distinct values in the first column by the maximum value in the third column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have joined three tables into one, to receive the following table:

| client_name | country_name | num_customers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client 1 | Albania | 1 |
| Client 1 | Bosnia | 22 |
| Client 1 | Croatia | 2 |
| Client 1 | Germany | 2 |
| Client 1 | England | 1 |
| Client 1 | Macedonia | 4 |
| Client 1 | Montenegro | 3 |
| Client 1 | Serbia | 4502 |
| Client 1 | Turkey | 1 |
| Client 2 | Belgium | 921 |
| Client 2 | England | 3 |
| Client 2 | Malta | 3 |
| Client 2 | Romania | 7 |
| Client 2 | Sweden | 1 |
| Client 3 | Latvia | 1 |
| Client 3 | Lithuania | 1848 |
| Client 4 | Italy | 143 |
| Client 5 | Albania | 1 |
| Client 5 | Algeria | 4 |
| Client 5 | Armenia | 4 |
| Client 5 | Austria | 3 |
| Client 5 | Azerbaijan | 1 |
| Client 5 | Belgium | 5746 |

My query for joining these three tables looks like this:

```
SELECT c1.client_name, c2.country_name, count(c3.customer_id) AS num_customers
FROM 
clients c1
LEFT JOIN countries c2 ON c1.fk_country = c2.country_id
LEFT JOIN customers c3 ON c1.fk_customer = c3.customer_id
GROUP BY c1.client_name, c2.country_name;
```

NOW! I need to expand this query so that my table only includes the country per each client with the maximum number of customers. So the final table should look like this:

| client_name | country_name | num_customers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client 1 | Serbia | 4502 |
| Client 2 | Belgium | 921 |
| Client 3 | Lithuania | 1848 |
| Client 4 | Italy | 143 |
| Client 5 | Belgium | 5746 |

I tried adding a having clause or cross joining max(num_customers) but could only return one row.
Help please?!

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x you can do this easily with window functions or a CTE.

Comment: Why are you using LEFT JOIN?

Comment: You might look into rollups

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT client_name, country_name, num_customers
FROM (SELECT c1.client_name, c2.country_name, COUNT(*) AS num_customers,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c1.client_name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM clients c1 JOIN
           countries c2
           ON c1.fk_country = c2.country_id JOIN
           customers c3
           ON c1.fk_customer = c3.customer_id
      GROUP BY c1.client_name, c2.country_name
     ) ccc
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  I switched the joins to inner joins, under the assumptions that all clients have a country.  Perhaps you have clients in [Bar Tawil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bir_Tawil).

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fbc49e5d434a1c43d1e885f7da2bd49) is a db<>fiddle showing that the syntax works.

Comment: I followed your code, but when I try using window functions I am getting:
"Select is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting FOR, LOCK, TABLE, VALUES, WITH, '('
and I also get an error if I try to run the code, it tells me my syntax is wrong (I used your code).
I am using MySQL server 8.0.23 and workbench.

Comment: @user15005160 . . . I added a db<>fiddle, showing that the syntax works.